# How to CSS select Angular-Material table tbody?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to style an Angular material table's `tbody`, but these selectors are not working:

`.mat-table tbody` and `table tbody`

Is their a way to style the `tbody` only?

~~Also, is their a way to wrap the `tbody` inside a `div`?~~

Comment: First, You can `never` wrap a tbody inside a div, why would you do that? A tbody can only be inside a table. Second, you have to check your dev tools how angular material defines the styles for their components and overwrite them in the same way.

Comment: I already checked the dev tools, and I am selecting the element properly, however, I think Angular loads the table elements after it loads the css, so my styles aren't taking effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .mat-table{/*apply you css code here*/}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I just added tbody to the end: ```::ng-deep .mat-table```

Comment: ::ng-deep is going to be deprecated, is there any other way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: @Asutosh Hi! It's been a while since your comment but I found some interesting info about this. Maybe it's useful for you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160 and https://blog.angular.io/the-new-state-of-css-in-angular-bec011715ee6#12af